# Tkinter create_rectangle doesn't draw anything

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a schedule maker and I want the schedules to be able to be viewed by using Tkinter. However the create_rectangle function isn't working, the rectangle just isn't being drawn. This is the code in question.

```
    elif command[0] == "show":

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Jonjot v0.1")
        root.geometry("350x270")
        root.resizable(False, False)

        canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=350, height=270)
        canv.pack_propagate(False)
        canv.delete("all")

        for lesson_data in memory[command[1]][command[2]].values():
            
            canv.create_text((int(lesson_data[3]) - 1) * 70 + 1, lesson_data[5] // 2, text=lesson_data[0], font=("Helvetica", 7), fill=subject_color[lesson_data[4]][1], anchor="nw")
            canv.create_text(int(lesson_data[3]) * 70, lesson_data[5] // 2, text=lesson_data[4], font=("Helvetica", 7), fill=subject_color[lesson_data[4]][1], anchor="ne")
            canv.create_text((int(lesson_data[3]) - 1) * 70 + 1, lesson_data[6] // 2, text=lesson_data[1], font=("Helvetica", 7), fill=subject_color[lesson_data[4]][1], anchor="sw")
            canv.create_text(int(lesson_data[3]) * 70, lesson_data[6] // 2, text=lesson_data[2], font=("Helvetica", 7), fill=subject_color[lesson_data[4]][1], anchor="se")

            color = subject_color[lesson_data[4]][0]
            canv.create_rectangle((int(lesson_data[3]) - 1) * 70 + 1, lesson_data[5], lesson_data[3] * 70, lesson_data[6], fill=subject_color[lesson_data[4]][0]) #<--- THIS is the part that doesn't work
            canv.pack()

        root.mainloop()
```

Mind you, the text is added just fine, and I'm getting no errors in the console.

Full code at https://hastebin.skyra.pw/evuropitus.prolog (it saved in wrong pl idk how to fix D: ), you also need a .json file so copy this and put it in the same directory:

`{"class": {"7E": {"1": ["7E", "KSu", "BE212", "1", "SV", 5, 60], "2": ["7E", "MEk", "BE212", "1", "SP", 70, 120], "3": ["7E", "SBr", "IDH1", "1", "ID", 140, 220], "4": ["7E", ".", "M\u00e4ssen", "1", "LU", 235, 255], "5": ["7E", "CLa", "STK", "1", "TK", 260, 310], "6": ["7E", "AJF", "BE214", "1", "EN", 325, 375], "7": ["7E", "TAn", "S78", "1", "SO", 390, 455]}}, "teacher": {"KSu": {"1": ["7E", "KSu", "BE212", "1", "SV", 5, 60]}, "MEk": {"2": ["7E", "MEk", "BE212", "1", "SP", 70, 120]}, "SBr": {"3": ["7E", "SBr", "IDH1", "1", "ID", 140, 220]}, "": {}, ".": {"4": ["7E", ".", "M\u00e4ssen", "1", "LU", 235, 255]}, "CLa": {"5": ["7E", "CLa", "STK", "1", "TK", 260, 310]}, "AJF": {"6": ["7E", "AJF", "BE214", "1", "EN", 325, 375]}, "TAn": {"7": ["7E", "TAn", "S78", "1", "SO", 390, 455]}}, "hall": {"BE212": {"1": ["7E", "KSu", "BE212", "1", "SV", 5, 60], "2": ["7E", "MEk", "BE212", "1", "SP", 70, 120]}, "IDH1": {"3": ["7E", "SBr", "IDH1", "1", "ID", 140, 220]}, "M\u00e4ssen": {"4": ["7E", ".", "M\u00e4ssen", "1", "LU", 235, 255]}, "STK": {"5": ["7E", "CLa", "STK", "1", "TK", 260, 310]}, "BE214": {"6": ["7E", "AJF", "BE214", "1", "EN", 325, 375]}, "S78": {"7": ["7E", "TAn", "S78", "1", "SO", 390, 455]}}}` then run the python file, run the two commands `load <the json file name without extension>` and `show class 7E`

I've tried moving lines of code, changing the color format (e.g. `green` to `#00ff00`), asking ChatGPT (unhelpful), changing variable names, asking the python discord server (no response) and googling (no results of anything similar). I am expecting the rectangle to, yknow, exist??

Comment: It is hard to reproduce the issue without sample data for `memory`, `subject_color`, etc.  So it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 I sent a link to the full code, if you'd like to try it you can copy it into IDLE or whatever IDE you use and try it there... but you're right I should add a sample memory, I'll do that now

Comment: I don't know what values you input in the console that produces the issue, so that is why you should provide sample data.  Also what are the type of the input data, if they are all strings, then what do you expect the result of `lesson_data[3]*70`?

Comment: I've added example data, hope it helps? :D

Comment: I can't believe it... not only is asking ChatGPT for help worthless it's literally harmful. I wrote to turn lesson_data[3] into an integer, chatgpt removed it, and I've had the problem since... thanks for pointing that out, it's still not perfect but at least the rectangles show up on the screen now :D I'll be marking this post as solved shortly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As @acw1668 pointed out, when asking ChatGPT it had removed a str->int conversion, which made the number 2222222... 70 times, instead of 140. Readding the conversion doesn't quite solve the issue but at least the rectangles are drawn on the screen now.